# Can a word that sounds the same as the way it is spelt be an initialism and an acronym?

Tags: acronyms, initialisms

Initialisms are pronounced as words and acronyms are spelt letters.  However, some words sound the same, said and spelt.

e.g. Input Output can be abbreviated as IO. It can be spelt *I-O* or pronounced *Io* as in the moon/god. There is no way to tell the difference in how it is said or written.

Is a word which is pronounced the way it is spelt, an initialism, an acronym or both?

Comment: I'd say yes: the same way a word can be both a verb and a noun. So "IO" is a [Homograph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph).

Comment: I rarely, if ever, see _input/output_ shortened to anything other than _I/O_.

Comment: Considering your OP and your comments, it seems that the title of your question should be edited to indicate your specific focus on IO. I'd rather you or a more senior ELU member do the edit, so for now I'm waiting for that or feedback on this comment.

Comment: @sarah I have tried to clarify the question. Its not specific to IO, but it is the only example I can think of right now.

Comment: If they both sound the same, how does it matter whether the person is "really" pronouncing the letters separately or the word? What does it even mean?

Comment: @Gnawme, put your comment as an answer.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR The difference between an initialism and an acronym appears to be whether it is pronounced as a word or it is spelt. So the question is; if there is no way to tell the difference, can it be both.

Comment: @PeterLawrey But, I think ending the question with _So, is IO an initialism, an acronym or both?_ gives the impression that that is the main point or the question.

Comment: @sarah I have changed the question, to make it clearer that its not about just one word.

Comment: The question has it backwards. An initialism is pronounced as individual letters. Examples: "USA", "BBC". An acronym is pronounced as a word using the language's orthography. Examples: "scuba", "radar".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the difference between acronyms and initialisms. Something can be both, or just one and not the other.

[**Acronym**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/acronym):

> a word formed from the initial letters or groups of letters of words in a set phrase or series of words, as *Wac*  from *Women's Army Corps*, *OPEC*  from *Organization of Petroleum Exporting Countries*,  or *loran*  from *long-range navigation*.

**[Initialism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Initialism)**:

> 1. a name or term formed from the initial  letters of a group of words and pronounced as a separate word, as *NATO*  for *North Atlantic Treaty organization*;  an acronym.
> 2. a set of initials  representing a name, organization, or the like, with each letter pronounced separately, as *FBI*  for *Federal Bureau of Investigation*.
> 3. the practice of using initials  or forming words from initials.

As you can see, *WAC, OPEC* and *NATO* are both acronyms and initialisms because they're a bunch of initials that you can pronounce as a word.

*FBI* on the other hand is a bunch of initials you cannot pronounce as a word; it's an initialism but not an acronym.

And finally, *loran* is pronounced as a word, but isn't only taken from initial letters; it's an acronym but not an initialism.

So for *IO*:

- If you pronounce *IO* as a word (like Greek "io"), it's an acronym.
- If you pronounce *IO* as letters I-O ("eye oh"), it's not an acronym.
- In both cases, *IO* is an initialism.

Comment: My question is; How would you tell is someone has pronounced something as `I-O` or `io` given they sound the same?  Is this a question of intent?

Comment: The problem is the word is phonetic. It sounds the same as it is spelt.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - you can only tell if someone means Io or IO given the context of what they're talking about. "Of all the moons of Jupiter Io is my favourite." "It looks like you're having a problem with the IO on COM4."

Comment: Ah, well the Greek word *io* is pronounced "ee-yoh" but sometimes "eye oh" in English. But *IO* is pronounced as "eye oh", and we have no idea whether the speaker is thinking of anglicised "io" or initials I-O, so I think it's fine to call it an acronym, but I probably wouldn't.

Comment: @MattЭллен, In your second example, was IO an initialism or an acronym? ;)

Comment: Context and local practice are the key.  The software product CICS is pronounced "kicks" in the UK, spelled out as C.I.C.S in the US and pronounced as "cheeks" in Italy for example.

Comment: @Wudang Yes, but the question here is a special case about a thing that usually sounds the same as a word ("io") and when spelled out (as "I. O.").

Comment: Doh!  (slaps head).

Comment: Seems like we might have two related questions here: 1 Can something be an initialism and an acronym? 2. Is IO an initialism, or an acronym or both?

Comment: My understanding was that the two were mutually exclusive, as Grammar Girl says here: http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/acronyms-grammar.aspx However, either she and I were always wrong, or we were once right but are now wrong because what what once wrong has become right by virtue of its popularity.

Answer (score -1):

It's an initialised (not *initialized*) acronym, or an acronymal initialism.

Comment: *[Initialized](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/initialize)* is a valid way of spelling *[initialised](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/initialize)*.

Comment: Not to be taken seriously but... http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=initialised&word2=initialized

Comment: @Hugo, Also, PeterLawrey: I suggested *initialised* to distinguish from the existing word "initialized* [AmE], since my intention is a derivation from *initialism*.   
The downticks are based on this misunderstanding, I guess.